# What does this command mean: EGLExt.eglPresentationTimeANDROID(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, when)?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview, egl

I could not find any documentation about this command. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGLExt

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGLExt.html#eglPresentationTimeANDROID(android.opengl.EGLDisplay,%20android.opengl.EGLSurface,%20long)

https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/ANDROID/EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time.txt

> the time at which the current color buffer of  should be
>       presented to the viewer